# Problem faced during the installation of Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor(installer)

Tags: android, installation, sdk, processor, amd-processor

I am trying to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor(installer) but whenever I try to install it, I face the following error

```
    Preparing "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gvm-windows_v1_6_0.zip
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\1.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\2.1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\auto\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\instantapps\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\market_apk_expansion\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\market_licensing\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\simulators\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\webdriver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skiaparser\1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors
HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac.
Please file a bug against Android Studio.
Done
```

I even uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it again but then also the issue is not solved.

- OS Version:- 10.0.14393 Build 14393
- BIOS Version/Date:- American Megatrends Inc. F1, 11-03-2013
- Bios Mode:- UEFI
- Processor:- Intel(R)Core(TM)i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3300 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Pro...
- CPU:- Intel(R)Core(TM)i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- Memory:- 4.0 GB DDR3

Comment: At least [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64816081/edit) and include the specs of your machine including: CPU, RAM, OS version, and what is your virtualization configuration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#choose-windows-hypervisor

Comment: No one can give you step-by-step directions if you don't answer the questions I already raised. Please use your favorite search engine for finding out your exact model of CPU on your PC or changes to BIOS settings to enable virtualization. Otherwise the link I provided is the best place to start. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/295004)

Comment: My virtualization is already enabled.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have added the required details said by you.

Comment: You are running an old version of Windows 10. Unclear why installer is detecting AMD when you have Intel CPU. I would double check what hypervisor you need: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows if you are running other VMs. Otherwise try a manual install of HAXM: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-haxm-intel

Comment: Ok Sir. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Thanks to the suggestion of @MorrisonChang , I manually installed HAXM from the github repository and that solved my problem.  https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases